# how to make animate.css(plugin) work instantly on live site load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I tried animate.css library which is working fine in my localhost and jsfiddle but in live site it is not taking action immediately, meaning animate option for the particular div is not happening at the start itself instead the div appears in the specified position at first then it comes from top or whatever effect i am giving.

I think this might be server loading time problem. Might be due to slow loading i can able to see the actual position first then the css class animation is taking place. Am not sure how to over come this.

[**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WL9da/1/) with code as in the live site but in js it is working fine.

I tried by giving the class directly in the markup itself instead through js because i thought js may load lately, even though i can able to see the static position on loading the site then the animation taking place from top to bottom

```
<div id="box" class="animated fadeInDownBig">Checking</div>
```

I tried by the js way too but no effect. Any idea on what happening here?

Comment: When I reload http://jsfiddle.net/WL9da/1/show/, it slides down immediately.

Comment: I said this in question itself. Its working in js fiddle but not in live site

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your question. After your comment and thorough rereading, I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your div html code is rendered in browser immediately and as you are calling

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#box').addClass('animated fadeInDownBig');
});
```

after document load. So, it is simple working according to your code after the document load it adds your animated fadeInDownBig effect. if the library you are using is just simple CSS file then I would recommend you this instead calling after document load

```
<div id="box" class="animated fadeInDownBig">Checking</div>
```

And if you got other js files etc in your library then use this code

```
#box {
width:60%;
height:60%;
left:20%;
top:20%;
background-color:red;
position:fixed;
display:none;
}

<div id="box" class="animated">Checking</div>

$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#box').css('display','block').addClass('fadeInDownBig');
});
```

And far as you are saying it's working fine on your localhost this might be due to it loads every library and files immediately on localhost so $(document).ready is called immediately.

Comment: Ya that is why i tried with markup instead of js like this `<div id="box" class="animated fadeInDownBig">Checking</div>` even though not an immediate effect taking place. Thanks

Comment: Nope. I tried by not using the js just mark up alone but it didn't work but in fiddle this way it works

Comment: did you try another way i said above by display=none and then in js display=block?

Comment: Just now i tried this without knowing your answer this works good

Comment: you are welcome. @sun would you plz give me up vote for my smile?